# Custom timeout configuration per operation using Spring

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am using a Soap WS and I have to customize timeout configuration per operation. The customization is actually done with `cxf` and its `http-conf:conduit`, which cannot be customized to the operation level.

My actual configuration is :

```
<bean id="proxyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="serviceClass" value="com.package.PortType" />
   <property name="address" ref="URL_WS" />
</bean>

<bean id="URL_WS" class="java.lang.String">
     <constructor-arg value="http://serveraddress/Service"/>         
</bean>

<http-conf:conduit name="http://serveraddress/Service.*"> 
    <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="10000" ReceiveTimeout="10000"/> 
</http-conf:conduit>
```

With this configuration, all the timeout of this WS are up to 10000ms.

As explained above, I would like to customize it to the operation level, I have found [this link](http://trimplement.com/custom-operation-timeouts-for-apache-cxf-based-soap-clients/) and tried to follow the process, but I'm in front of a problem of implementation, but I only `com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.QNameUtils` in my classpath which has for the factory-method :
`public static QName newQName(Node paramNode)`, method which takes a `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

I tried to change the code with this implementation coming to:

```
<bean id="proxyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
 <property name="delegate">
  <jaxws:client serviceClass="com.package.PortType" address="URL_WS" >
   <jaxws:outInterceptors>
    <bean class="com.package.CustomTimeoutInterceptor">
     <property name="receiveTimeoutByOperationName">
      <map key-type="javax.xml.namespace.QName" value-type="java.lang.Long">
       <entry value="10">
        <key>
         <bean class="com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.QNameUtils" factory-method="newQName">
          <!-- I don't know what to put here -->
         </bean>
        </key>
       </entry>
      </map>
     </property>
    </bean>
   </jaxws:outInterceptors>
  </jaxws:client>
 </property>
</bean>
```

The `Node`'s implementation I have is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl`. I don't know which `NodeImpl`' subclass I have to use and how to create it to make it working in a bean way, I'm kinda losing myself in the documentation with these different implementations and these different dom Levels. 
I just would like to create an Object subClass of `Node` which would work in this `QNameUtils` method
OR
find a different way to customize my configuration

Comment: Gary - check out this blog entry: http://trimplement.com/custom-operation-timeouts-for-apache-cxf-based-soap-clients/

Comment: R4J - That's actually the link I talk about in my question

Comment: Im blind :( Can you give me CXF and Spring versions?

Comment: Spring 3.0.0 & cxf 2.7.*

Comment: cxf 2.7.4 more precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem, here is the working solution:

I kept the [CustomTimeoutInterceptor](http://trimplement.com/custom-operation-timeouts-for-apache-cxf-based-soap-clients/) of the link, mixed the solution with the help of [this link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201305.mbox/%3CCAH9fUpYxuZSv0H81hK9eX75a+F16WLjGmyLa1phZCck95bsUFA@mail.gmail.com%3E).

I also kept my initial configuration, and I found that the `javax.xml.namespace.QName` had a factory method. I just added this part to my configuration:

```
<!-- Creation of the bean for the interceptor -->
<bean id="timeoutSetter" class="com.package.CustomTimeoutInterceptor">
  <property name="receiveTimeoutByOperationName">
    <map key-type="javax.xml.namespace.QName" value-type="java.lang.Long">
      <entry value="20000">
        <key>
          <bean class="javax.xml.namespace.QName" factory-method="valueOf">
            <constructor-arg value="{http://serveraddress/Service}Operation1" />
          </bean>
        </key>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- I had the interceptor the list of outInterceptors -->
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
      <ref bean="timeoutSetter"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```